# Index not getting created using stored procedure - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have this stored procedure to create index on table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_index (
    in_tb        VARCHAR2,
    in_index     VARCHAR2,
    in_columns   VARCHAR2,
    lc_status    OUT          NUMBER
) AS
    lc_affected   NUMBER;
    lc_stmt       VARCHAR2(1500);
BEGIN
    lc_stmt := 'BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''CREATE INDEX '
               || in_index
               || ' ON '
               || in_tb
               || ' ('
               || in_columns
               || ')''; END;';

    dbms_output.put_line(lc_stmt);
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement(lc_stmt);
    lc_affected := SQL%rowcount;
    dbms_output.put_line('AFFECTED -->' || lc_affected);
    IF ( lc_affected > 0 ) THEN
        lc_status := 1;
    ELSE
        lc_status := 1;
    END IF;

END create_index;
/
```

I execute the stored procedure using:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    lc_status   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    create_index('TABLE_1_LOAD', 'ON_RUN_INDEX', 'MY_ID', lc_status);
END;
```

However, the index is not getting created in table `TABLE_1_LOAD`.

The output is:

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX ON_RUN_INDEX ON TABLE_1_LOAD (MY_ID)'; END;
AFFECTED -->

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I am not able to understand why the stored procedure is not creating indexes. Can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamic statement you are trying to run via `exec_ddl_statement` is not DDL. It contains DDL, but embedded in an anonymous PL/SQL block, which is not the same thing. It looks like the `dbms_utility` procedure is just silently ignoring it for that reason.

If you simplify your statement to remove the unnecessary block then it will work:

```
...
BEGIN
    lc_stmt := 'CREATE INDEX '
               || in_index
               || ' ON '
               || in_tb
               || ' ('
               || in_columns
               || ')';

...
```

Demo:

```
create table table_1_load (my_id number);

Table TABLE_1_LOAD created.
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_index (
    in_tb        VARCHAR2,
    in_index     VARCHAR2,
    in_columns   VARCHAR2,
    lc_status    OUT          NUMBER
) AS
    lc_affected   NUMBER;
    lc_stmt       VARCHAR2(1500);
BEGIN
    lc_stmt := 'CREATE INDEX '
               || in_index
               || ' ON '
               || in_tb
               || ' ('
               || in_columns
               || ')';

    dbms_output.put_line(lc_stmt);
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement(lc_stmt);
    lc_affected := SQL%rowcount;
    dbms_output.put_line('AFFECTED -->' || lc_affected);
    IF ( lc_affected > 0 ) THEN
        lc_status := 1;
    ELSE
        lc_status := 1;
    END IF;

END create_index;
/

Procedure CREATE_INDEX compiled
```

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    lc_status   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    create_index('TABLE_1_LOAD', 'ON_RUN_INDEX', 'MY_ID', lc_status);
END;
/

CREATE INDEX ON_RUN_INDEX ON TABLE_1_LOAD (MY_ID)
AFFECTED -->


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The 'affected' number is still null, because `execute_ddl_statement` doesn't cause `SQL%rowcount` to be set, so you can't rely on that to tell you anything. But the index has been created:

```
select object_type, object_name from user_objects where created > trunc(sysdate);

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME                   
------------------- ------------------------------
TABLE               TABLE_1_LOAD                  
PROCEDURE           CREATE_INDEX                  
INDEX               ON_RUN_INDEX
```

---

You *could* run your original statement with `execute immediate`, and that would actually set `SQL%rowcount`, but as you still haven't run any DML it's meaningless really. To show that, with the (still unnecessary) anonymous block you get 1; without the block, using the same simplified statement as above, you get 0.